# Why doesn't my MySQL update query work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm making a blog edit page, but my edit page doesn't do anything. Why doesn't my update query work? I'm collecting the data from an old blog and inserting it into my form. And then I'm trying to update it using my update query.

I think this is the code you need:

```
<?php

include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;
if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

    if (empty($title) or empty($content)){
        $error ='All fields are required!';
    } else {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE articles SET article_title = ?, article_content = ? WHERE id=:id");

        $id = $_POST ['id'];
        $query->bindValue(1, $title);
        $query->bindValue(2 ,$content);
        $query->bindValue ('id', $id);

        $query->execute();
        header('Location: index.php');


    }
}   
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $article->fetch_data($id)



?>

    <?php

} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

?>

<form action="aanpassen.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="" name="id" value="<?php echo  $data['article_id']; ?>">
    <input class="titleform" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Blog naam" value="<?php echo $data['article_title']; ?>" />
    <textarea id="summernote" name="content" rows="15" cols="50">
                                <?php echo $data['article_content'] ?> </textarea>
    <input class="buttonclass" type="submit" value="Aanmaken" /> </form>
```

Comment: Why doesn't my update query work? You are facing any errors?

Comment: why are you mixing placeholders in the sql?

Comment: the error will be "$pdo" you are not declaring it.

Comment: Why have you done _nothing whatsoever_ to check whether your query was successful or not, and if not, what error message the database has for you? Please don’t ask how, now - this is something you can read up on everywhere, and actually rather should have done before you came here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a *"Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters"* error.

Change `?` to placeholders, and change to `bindValue()`:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE articles SET article_title = :title, 
                        article_content = :content WHERE id=:id");
$id = $_POST ['id'];
$query->bindValue('title', $title);
$query->bindValue('content', $content);
$query->bindValue('id', $id);
$query->execute();
```

Or use only positional parameters.

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me?

Comment: @Mr.Code Did you try to `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after your `$pdo = new PDO`?

Comment: It gives me a "HTTP ERROR 500" an redirects me aanpassen.php

Answer (score 0):

The form element `id` was missing a `type` attribute - probably defaulted to `text`

Whilst probably not going to cause errors the mixing of placeholder types in the prepared statement is unusual. The `id` placeholder was missing the colon in the `bindValue` call - again possibly OK though to my mind it should always be used in named placeholders.

If the `prepared statement` failed the initial stage there was no logic to test for it.

```
<?php

    $error=false;
    include_once('includes/connection.php');
    include_once('includes/article.php');

    $article = new Article;

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && $pdo ){
        if ( isset( $_POST ['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['content'] ) ) {

            $id = $_POST ['id'];
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $content = nl2br( $_POST['content'] );

            if ( empty( $title ) or empty( $content ) or empty( $id ) ){

                $error='All fields are required!';

            } else {
                $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE articles SET article_title = :title, article_content = :content WHERE id=:id");
                if( $query ){

                    $query->bindValue( ':title', $title );
                    $query->bindValue( ':content' ,$content );
                    $query->bindValue( ':id', $id );

                    $result=$query->execute();
                    header( sprintf( 'Location: index.php?status=%s', $result ? 'ok' : 'failed' ) );
                } else {
                    exit('bad foo - unable to prepare sql query');
                }
            }
        } else {
            exit( sprintf( "<pre>check all required fields are named correctly\n\n%s</pre>", print_r( $_POST, true ) ) );
        }
    }

    if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && $article ) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $data = $article->fetch_data( $id );
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

?>

<form action="aanpassen.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo  $id; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="title" class="titleform" placeholder="Blog naam" value="<?php echo $data['article_title']; ?>" />
    <textarea name="content" id="summernote" rows="15" cols="50"><?php echo $data['article_content'] ?></textarea>

    <input type="submit" class="buttonclass" value="Aanmaken" />
</form>
<?php
    if( $error )printf('<h1>%s</h1>',$error);
?>
```

Comment: where does the code fail do you know? does it redirect to `?status=ok/failed` or not even get that far?

Comment: i am not getting any errors, as soon as i click on the submit button it just redirects me to the index.php, but nothing happend.